# Method definition not found

Tags: objective-c

What am I doing wrong?  This is the .h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <sqlite3.h>

@class ReaderViewController;

@interface ReaderAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> { 
    UIWindow *window; 
    ReaderViewController *viewController; 
} 

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window; 
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet ReaderViewController *viewController; 

- (void)checkForDatabase; 
//- (void)SQLiteConnection: (NSString *)defaultDBPath; 
@end
```

The error is shown here:

[image: screen shot of compile results]

Comment: Well, that screenshot doesn't show the error message. It just says that the compiler failed. Can you post the specific compiler error message. Also, were is the class ReaderViewController defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the `[self checkForDatabase]` method which doesn't appear to exist in the .m file.

---

The *Incomplete Implementation* warning is because you have declared the `checkForDatabase` method in your interface

The *Method Definition* error is because you are attempting to call the missing method in the `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method.

Answer (score 1):

You have failed to implement `checkForDatabase` in `ReaderAppDelegate.m` (or in any other file you're linking into the project). You said you would in the header, and then you didn't.

Comment: Rob, theChrisKent:  I put it in a file called SQLiteDB.m... is that not allowed in XCode?  I wanted to separate ALL of the SQLite methods in one file.  I guess I need to ask:  how do I do that?

Comment: You can do that, but you'd need to do it as either an extension or category on ReaderAppDelegate. http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocCategories.html